# Mx record for subdomain

Tags: cpanel, mx-record

My domain mybasiccrm.com is hosted on hostgator.com

The subdomain tr1.mybasiccrm.com is hosted on tr8.mybasiccrm.com

I have created an MX record on the server tr8 for the domain tr1.mybasiccrm.com  but when I check this http://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=mx%3atr1.mybasiccrm.com&run=toolpage
it says that "No Records Exist"

How can I have a proper mx recort for tr1.mybasiccrm.com ?

PS: I can send an email from my gmail account to the address email@tr1.mybasiccrm.com without a problem.

Thank you all!

Comment: Did you create an MX record with your Name Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is sub domain of TLD: mybasiccrm.com, make sure that you are adding MX for your subdomain “tr1.mybasiccrm.com” in  mybasiccrm.com's DNS zone as long as you do not have separate DNS zone of your sub domain.

→ Collect exact MX value, you need to set for tr1.mybasiccrm.com.

→ Open DNS zone of  mybasiccrm.com and add MX record:

```
Record type: MX
Record name: tr1
Priority: 0
Value: MX value of  tr1.mybasiccrm.com
```

Once it is done, check in any online tool